# javascript json url get not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is my code to pull from a server a json file ... 
yet I am getting undefined thou if I change the url to something else it works...I am also using the new standard of promise for doing asynchronous JS

Exactly the same but different url this below code works...

```js
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
};

getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/bob_dylan').then(function(data) {
    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result); //you can comment this, i used it to debug

    result.innerText = data.result; //display the result in an HTML element
}, function(status) { //error detection....
  alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

This is the error code and is the same as above...

```js
//using the promise method
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
};

getJSON('http://collidr-vidya.herokuapp.com/api/v1/scores').then(function(data) {
    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result); //you can comment this, i used it to debug

    result.innerText = data.result; //display the result in an HTML element
}, function(status) { //error detection....
  alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

What am I doing wrong....

Comment: Do see any error message in your console? Have you tried doing a search for that error on the web?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have `result` in your response .... replace `data.result` by `data.scores`

```
getJSON('http://collidr-vidya.herokuapp.com/api/v1/scores').then(function (data) {
debugger;
alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.scores); //you can comment this, i used it to debug

result.innerText = data.scores; //display the result in an HTML element
}, function (status) { //error detection....
alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Further more I have even tried a NON promise method for getting the url from the server...

This below is working ...

```js
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
};
getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/bob_dylan', function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result);
    result.innerText = data.result;
  }
});
```

Same code different url not working...

```js
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
};
getJSON('http://collidr-vidya.herokuapp.com/api/v1/scores', function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result);
    result.innerText = data.result;
  }
});
```